# how to write the output of iostream to buffer, python3

Tags: python, string, io, stream, wrapper

I have a program that reads data from cli sys.argv[] and then writes it to a file.
I would like to also display the output to the buffer.

The manual says to use getvalue(), all I get are errors.
[Python3 manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html)

```
import io
import sys

label = sys.argv[1]
domain = sys.argv[2]
ipv4 = sys.argv[3]
ipv6 = sys.argv[4]

fd = open( domain+".external", 'w+')
fd.write(label+"."+domain+".        IN AAAA "+ipv6+"\n")

output = io.StringIO()
output.write('First line.\n')
print('Second line.', file=output)

# Retrieve file contents -- this will be
# 'First line.\nSecond line.\n'
contents = output.getvalue()

# Close object and discard memory buffer --
# .getvalue() will now raise an exception.
output.close()

print(fd)
fd.getvalue()
```

error:

```
 # python3.4 makecustdomain.py bubba domain.com 1.2.3.4 '2001::1'

<_io.TextIOWrapper name='domain.com.external' mode='w' encoding='US-ASCII'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "makecustdomain.py", line 84, in <module>
    fd.getvalue()
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'getvalue
```

How do I output the data from io stream write function data to buffer as well as to file?

Comment: Where are you getting fd from?  It isn't a StringIO object.

Comment: @ Aereaux from string + sys.argv[]. here is the complete code. http://paste.ee/p/UkGpB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `open()` to open the file, so it isn't a StringIO object, but a file-like object.  To get the contents of the file after you write to it you can open the file with `mode = 'w+'`, and instead of `fd.getvalue()`, do:

```
fd.seek(0)
var = fd.read()
```

This will put the contents of the file into var.  This will also put you at the beginning of the file, though, so be carefully doing further writes.

Comment: I tried a few different ways, I never received any output   http://paste.ee/p/9QFL7

Comment: You need to seek back to the beginning by doing `fd.seek(0)`.

Comment: 'seek back?'  I tried putting it right after the fd declaration and everywhere in between. Never any output to the buffer.  :(

Comment: Just do it right before the read, otherwise you will overwrite part of the file.

Comment: Put both `fd.seek(0)` and `fd.read()` after the writes.  Also, `fd.read()` returns a value, so `print` that or assign it to a variable.